# I encounter NumberFormatException: null while using JSP

Tags: html, jsp

HTML code in mt.jsp

```
<input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" value="0"/>
<input type="submit" value="Transfer Money" onsubmit="mt.jsp"/>
```

JSP Scriptlet:

```
line 71:    String money="0";
line 72:    int amt1=0;
line 73:    money=request.getParameter("amt");
line 74:    amt1=Integer.parseInt(money);
```

An exception occurred processing JSP page /mt.jsp at line 74

root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

I want to know why i am encountering this exception while converting string to integer...

Html code in login.jsp

```
<form onsubmit="login.jsp">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value=""/></br>
       <label>Password</label>
       <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" value=""/></br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/></br>
 </form>
```

scriptlet in login.jsp:

```
if(resultset.next())
                    response.sendRedirect("mt.jsp");
                session.setAttribute("userID", uname);
```

Comment: are you opening the mt.jsp without the form submit? I mean how do you open it?

Comment: i opened mt.jsp after login.jsp but in mt.jsp i used onsubmit method...

Comment: the onsubmit method is wrong, this function should be in the form tag... also it only supports javascript code

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you don't expect the `amt parameter` to be `null` and you might be opening the url without passing this parameter.

So the solution is to check if the parameter is `null` before parse it, code example:

```
money=request.getParameter("amt");
if(money!=null){
   amt1=Integer.parseInt(money);
}
```

Comment: i tried this checking already but it only avoids the error but the value always appears to be NULL even though i enter some value it the text box named as "amt"

Comment: ok, please edit the question and post the login form html code

Comment: ýour login.jsp looks ok, but in the code `response.sendRedirect("mt.jsp")` you dont pass any amt parameter that will cause it to be null... for ie, if you do `response.sendRedirect("mt.jsp?amt=5")` it will return 5

Comment: mt.jsp?amt=0 - i changed so that thal null value is eliminated which caused numberformatexception